# using statement bodies in printf in C

Tags: c, printing

I am taking a course where we were doing a lot with systems level programming, and now we are getting to the point where we are starting the introduction to C. We are given some code and told to state the values printed out by each 'printf' statement. I know how to do regular printing statements in languages like Java and Python. But the code given has bodies to the print sections which I have not seen before. The statements are executed in the order A, B, C, D. Here is the code:

```
int t;   /* This variable is global */

{
   int t = 2;

   printf("%d\n", t);       /*  A  */
   {
      printf("%d\n", t);    /*  B  */
      t = 3;
   }
   printf("%d\n", t);       /*  C  */
}

{
   printf("%d\n", t);       /*  D  */
}
```

The part that confuses me is that some of the print statements have bodies. A print statement inside a print statement?

So here is what I am thinking: t = 2 so when we get to A, it executes the body within A first. So the first statement in that body is to print t which at this point is 2. Then after we print 2, we change the value in t to 3. After that we go to C which just prints t which is 3 (I guess? I'm not sure here). After that we go to the body that contains D. Int t is a global variable declared above, but it is never initialized (except in the first portion of code). So in the second portion that contains D, would there be an error since t is not initialized in that block of code?

```
2
3
3
Error
```

I feel like I am wrong.

Comment: They don't have bodies.  The braces (`{ }`) just create new scopes, and are unrelated to the `printf` statements.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Okay thanks. So would it instead print: 2, 3, 2, Error? Would the third value printed be a 2 since t is changed to 3 inside the scope of the braces? Also, is it correct to say that D is an error, or would it just print garbage values?

Comment: That happens because `t=2` on the fist call, then `t=3` for the next two, and finally `t is uninitialized` for the last call. (e.g. there is never a value set for the outer scoped `t` -- it is just declared `int t` in that scope)

Comment: Is `t` really global or a local variable?

Comment: The first line `int t; /* This variable is global */` cannot be, unless it is outside the function (which you didn't show).

Comment: Either this is pseudocode (i.e. not real code) or `t` is not actually global...

Comment: If it were global, there would be no error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a global variable t, which is initialized to 0 (AFAIK, all global variables in C are initialized to 0 if not explicity initialized)

Then, a block is opened and a local variable t is declared and initialized to 2, which shadows the global variable with the same name (in java this is an error, the compiler will complain and refuse to use the same name), for the whole block.

The first `printf`, which is inside the block, prints 2.

Then a nested block opens, with a `printf` in it. This printf will also use the local variable `t`, printing 2 again.

Then `t` is assigned 3. This `"t"` cannot be other than the local variable.

Then, the nested block closes and we are back into the first still opened block in which local t was declared. The printf here prints 3.

Then the first block finishes and so the local variable `t` is gone. A new block opens and the last `printf` prints the value of global variable `t`, which is the only one known in this block. It prints 0.

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces begin and end new scopes, just like they do with functions.

There are two "main blocks" in your program. One contains a definition of variable `t`, thus shadowing the global `t`. Therefore `2`, `2`, and `3` is printed out. The second block can access the global `t`, so the `printf` in the second block prints out the value of the global `t`.

Global variables are initialized to `0` by default, so the last `printf` call prints `0` to the screen.
Local variables are not initialized with any value, so the last `printf` call would yield undefined behavior.

The output is

```
2
2
3
```

and after that

```
0
```

if the "global" `t` really **is** global **or** (probably<sup>1</sup>) some random value if it is local.

---

<sup>1</sup> Undefined behavior occurs. Anything may happen. In this case, it's probably a random value getting printed out.

Comment: all 4 of the calls to printf() will print known values,  so this answer was correct until the line: `if the "global t really is global.....`  everything from then on is not correct.    It is obvious (to me) that the real item being tested/demonstrated in the code snippet is the scoping rules.

Comment: @user3629249 Could you explain your last sentence, please? And what exactly is not correct in your opinion?

Comment: The code snippet is testing the OPs knowledge about scope of a variable, not about their knowledge of the printf() function.   This objective (knowledge of scope of a variable) is clearly indicated by the requirement to indicate what would be printed by each call to printf().  the OPs posted code clearly states that the first 't' variable is global so it has to be in the file global area, so it is initialized to 0.    So no question that the first 't' variable is in the global scope.  So it is not `undefined behaviour`

Comment: @user362949 But then, technically, that's not wrong. I stated that **if** `t` is local **then** undefined behavior follows.